# Mongodb, query within key-pair values

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any way to query inside this struture by the object keys of `roles`?

```
   interface UsersModel{
         _id: string;
         email: string;
         roles: { [key: string]: RolesType[] };
    }
```

For now I get the data into `users` like:

```
roles: {
   $ne: null
}
```

and then

```
const finalResult = users.filter(u => Object.keys(u.roles).includes('objectKeyIwant'));
```

Can this be done on the mongodb side and avoid getting all the data then filter it?

**Data examples:**
The user collection is like this:

```
{
    _id: '610baff85c071a2bd59dc84f',
    email: 'some@email.com',
    roles : {
        "shop1" : [ 
            "shop_stock_manager"
        ],
        "shop2" : [ 
            "shop_admin", 
            "shop_stock_manager"
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want to get all the users that have any role in `shop2`.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: could you provide a sample json of one of your user doc ?

Comment: Guys, I've added the details in the question.

Comment: could you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
db.collection.find({"roles.shop2":{$ne:[]}})
```